Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'csrf')
I have a component where I send a form and when I click on the button I get the error of the image, I have installed the latest version and already updated everything but that error remains.
Note: this happens in any component
I am using PHP 8.3, I updated everything and the problem only occurs on the production server, locally I have never had that problem

Edit your question and share the code block which throws this error.
